# What's a good version control for a Mac environment?

Tags: iphone, macos, version-control

I'm a Windows developer looking to do some Cocoa dev on a Mac.  I'm familiar with Subversion, TFS, Sourcegear Vault, CVS and VSS in a Windows environment.  What version control should I look at using in my new, unfamiliar Mac environment?

I will be doing 95% of the development, with the other 5% coming from one or two other people.  However, it is probably safe to assume I will be the only one making commits.

Is there a good Subversion client for Macs?  I have a repository already setup that I could use, but I also wouldn't mind using something else.  What do you recommend?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Personally, I would probably just use subversion from the command line. If you are looking for a nice GUI I have heard good things about:

http://versionsapp.com/

Comment: I'll second that.  I don't particularly like using the built in svn client in XCode, but I've been using Versions and XCode for a while and can't complain.

Answer (score 6):

Seeing as you're already in an unfamiliar environment,
why not go the whole hog and start using [git](http://git-scm.com/)?
Prebuilt binaries abound and for me, switching to git
this year brought me an increase in productivity.

You can also try [gitx](http://gitx.frim.nl/) which, amonst other things,
generates nice, colourful, London metro style graphs of
of your commits and merges.

Comment: Note that many people use "www.github.com" for hosting git projects with great success, and it has great guides for getting set up and using git on OS X.

Answer (score 5):

[Versions](http://versionsapp.com/) is a very good Subversion client for the Mac. There are lots of other clients available too.

I personally use Git for all my Mac projects. [Gitx](http://gitx.frim.nl/) is a good client. 
I you're willing to experiment, Git, in my opinion is arguably the most powerful revision control system you can get your hands on — but it does have a small learning curve. 
(You can always use the command line versions of git/svn/cvs—all of them work superbly)

Answer (score 2):

Get an account at http://beanstalkapp.com/ and then use http://versionsapp.com to connect to it.

Answer (score 2):

http://whygitisbetterthanx.com/

I use GIT, get it from here:
http://code.google.com/p/git-osx-installer/
Frankly speaking CVS and Subversion, others are just not good enough. People that still use them fall on 2 categories.

1. Because of legacy, they have to.
2. They are to lazy to learn something new.
3. Their IDE supports X.

Out of this 2, #1 is valid, if your org is already using something and the cost of change is too high, bummer, you need to take it. #2 is what happens to most people. #3 is pointless as source control inside an ide is meaningless, no real advantage/disadvantage, sure its nice, but I much rather have a better source control version than a button in my IDE.

REALLY USE GIT !.

Answer (score 1):

CVS and Subversion are both available for Macs.

Answer (score 1):

1. Subversion is installed by default on Leopard
2. The latest XCode knows about Subversion

so...

Comment: Why go by halves? Use CVS and make your suffering complete.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with fraca7.  Subversion support is built directly into XCode. I happen to think it's really great.
[Here's a link](http://developer.apple.com/tools/subversionxcode.html) to apple's docs on setting up svn with xcode.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I remember is the SCM support in Xcode limited to git, svn and cvs.
Thus I would choose some of them.
I personally prefer subversion.

Answer (score 1):

Xcode 3.1 has built in support for CVS, Subversion and Perforce.  I haven't used Perforce with Xcode, but a friend does and seems happy with it.  My company uses Subversion and it works reasonably well with Xcode, but it's a little rough compared to what you get with Eclipse or IntelliJ.

Beyond that, we use Subversion primarily from the command line, but my co-worker has taken a look at Versions and liked it.

Answer (score 1):

XCode 3.1 has built in support for Subversion SVN.

There is a GUI plugin called SCPlugin that works very well, pretty similar to tortoiseSVN on Windows but with less frills.

Here is the link http://scplugin.tigris.org/